# Why does this erlang code eat so much memory?

Tags: memory-leaks, erlang

I'm going through Cesarini and Thompson's "Erlang Programming" (O'Reilly) and I made a solution to 4-2 but after playing around with it there are two problems:

1. Every time I run go/3, "werl.exe" in windows chews up X amount of RAM. Every subsequent call takes up the same amount and it's never reclaimed.
2. If I run go(Message,10000,10) it eats up 1.4GB RAM and crashes

I thought that in my second case, Erlang should handle this no problem from what I've been reading, so my guess is that I've somehow introduced a memory leak? I read the sections on memory leaks and tail recursion and don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
-module(processRing).
-export([waitMessage/0,go/3]).

% Spawn M processes and pass Message around to each process N times
go(Message,M,N) ->

    ProcList = buildList(M),
    [H | T ] = ProcList,
    register(firstProc,H),
    H ! {self(), T, ProcList, Message, N}.

waitMessage() ->
    receive 
        {_, _, _, _, 0} ->
            io:format("end!", []);

        {From, [H|T], AllProcs, Message, N} ->
            %io:format("~w:~w from:~w~n n=~w",[self(),Message,From,N]),
            H ! {self(), T, AllProcs, Message, N},
            waitMessage();

        {From, [], AllProcs, Message, N} ->
            io:format("~w:~w (Last in list) from:~w n=~w~n",[self(),Message,From,N]),
            firstProc ! {self(), AllProcs, AllProcs, Message, N - 1},
            waitMessage();

        Other ->
            io:format("other:~w~n",[Other])
    end.

buildList(N) when N > 0 ->
    [spawn(processRing,waitMessage,[]) | buildList(N - 1)];

buildList(0) ->
    [].
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer issue #2.  But, when you register a process you are basically creating and setting a global variable, and that's a memory leak right there.

Comment: @Omnifarious: only a single process is registered.

Comment: Yes, but that process could potentially be holding onto all the others by reference.  Anyway, it looks like someone has really answered the question better than I, and while I was sort of right my idea wasn't the whole truth which is why I didn't leave it as an answer.  :-)  I'm an Erlang newbie myself.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I see what you mean. In Erlang registering only means putting an entry to a "global" lookup table containing the name and the process id. It has nothing to do with the life and heap of the process. Also a process holding the pid of another one doesn't mean anything. Don't think in terms of Java or C#, or stuff like that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProcList contains the list of Pids of all spawned processes. This list is received by all processes. For your example this means 10.000 x 10.000 Pids for each turn. That's quite a lot of memory!

Unless garbage collection can be set to get rid of the list as soon as the list is received, this won't work... try calling `erlang:garbage_collect()` before the `waitMessage()` tail calls.

Comment: Oh, the list is shrunk at each step, so it's just 10.000 x 5.000 Pids per turn :)

Comment: Ahhhhhh, of course! I'm coming from Java so I forget that these darn lists are copied every single time.

Comment: I tried using the garbage_collect() as you suggested, but memory usage still climbs with every call to go/3. Eg go(hello,5000,5) grows my werl.exe process by 5mb per call

Comment: You never kill your processes. Each call to go will leave 5000 (well, 4999) processes hanging around... The default heap size for a process is 233 words so if you use a 64-bit system that should add up to the missing 5MB.

Comment: Thanks again, I send a stop message to the processes now and it's all good. Yes, it's a 64 bit system. Thanks again, this is all starting to make a lot more sense now. I've just about optimized my solution so it doesn't pass the lists around either.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be entirely sure without seeing the "crash dump" but I suspect that the following might be causing some grief:

`[spawn(chap9q1,waitMessage,[]) | buildList(N - 1)];`

because your source listing shows that

`-module(processRing).` the module is named something different from what you are trying to get `spawn` to act on (module name is the first parameter).

In other words: you are trying to build a huge number of processes but every one of them will be failing and I suspect that the "garbage collection" will take some time to clean-up.

Comment: I bet the crash dump will be truncated, so it would yield no usable information. At least I've never seen crash dumps of 1.5 GB :o)

Comment: My mistake! I changed the name of the module before posting to the forum for clarity. It doesn't solve the problem, but good eye! It has to do with copying the gigantic lists every time